# how to read numbers with irregular spaces in R

Tags: r

I have my data in txt file, contain the following number, how to read into R 
I tied `fread` but did not work

```
Error in fread("x.txt") : 
  Expected sep (' ') but new line, EOF (or other non printing character) ends field 0 when detecting types (   first):
```

Here is the data:

```
 2    3    3    2    1    2    3    2    3     2     1     3     1     2

 1     1     3     2     3     1     2     1     2     3     3     2

 3     1     1     1     2     1     1     3     1     2     2     2

 1     3     1     1     3     2     3     3     1     1     2     2

     1     3     2     3     2     1     3     1     1     1     3     1

    1     3     1     2     3     3     2     2     2     2     3     3

 1     3     2     3     2     3     2     2     2     1     3     1
3     2     1     2     2     3     3     2     3     2     3     3

 2      1
```

Comment: It is not clear. How many lines do you have in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
x <- scan("x.txt")
data <- as.data.frame(x)
```